Linux Fedora suddenly much slower... only on one computer
I have two computers running fully updated Fedora 40. The two computers have the exact same packages installed. They are not identical, but very similar and bought at the same time: Dell Optiplex 7000 (SSF vs Micro). They have always performed essentially identically.
Yet, this week one of the two began to behave MUCH slower than the other. Around 1/3 the speed. Commands top, free, and the benchmarks for the NVME SSD's show no sign of problems. It does not seem to be any process slowing down the computer.
The one that has problems is the Micro, that has 16GB of DDR5 RAM vs 24GB of DDR4 of the SFF.
I tried working in different NVMEs, I tried switching to an older kernel (kernel-6.10.11 vs kernel-6.11.3)... Nothing...
Any ideas?

Visually compare the results of sudo journalctl  -b 0 on each system. Watch your kernel start up, discover its hardware, load drivers, start services, etc. Each message starts with a timestamp, the host that issued the log entry, the process name, the PID in [] of the issuer and a colon (:). Everything after the colon is a message from the programmer, intended to help the user understand the program's behavior. Read man logger for ONE way of producing log messages.

I changed the power consumption of my computer and probably forgot.
powerprofilesctl showed power-saver instead of balanced.
Stupid me, sorry.
